# Searching for scifi movie from the 2000's

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Looking for a movie I saw in the mid-2000's. I think some of it was set in Florida. A kid is being chased by government ops. They're trying to catch him before he is reunited with his people. They think he's an alien but he's really from a higher dimension of earth.

Scene at the end where the barrier between dimensions opens up and we see a giant city in the sky, kind of a utopian earth.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be *[Midnight Special](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2649554/)* (2016)?

The protagonist is a young  boy chased by the government. At the end of the film we see his futuristic city.

> Roy barrels through a roadblock, driving inside the perimeter as the Army scrambles to chase them. Alton and Sarah exit the car and run into the woods. Roy and Lucas lead the Army on a wild goose chase while Alton and Sarah reach the edge of a swamp. There, Alton creates a dome of light that engulfs much of Florida and surrounding states; everyone inside it can see the futuristic structures of a parallel world. Eventually, other beings of this world gather around Alton, and the entire dome disappears, taking Alton with it.
>
> <sub><sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Special_(film))</sup></sub>

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that the timescale is all wrong, but this was the first film I though of that matches the description

Comment: It's definitely the one that I immediately thought of, and I can't think of a better match, especially when the question calls out the other-world architecture.